# Patent ownership for inventions by employees on unpaid COVID leave

Tags: intellectual-property, employment, patents, israel

According to the employment contract, anything an employee comes up with, at any time (e.g. during weekends and completely unrelated to work) is the property of the company. It seems harsh but as prospective employees we were told it is "take it or leave it".

Suppose an employee was now put on unpaid leave due to the pandemic. They then come up with an invention that they wish to patent.

What is the legal position if the employee was put on unpaid leave? Who owns the patent?

What about if the employee used the workplaces' facilities such as workshops or labs to build a prototype? Perhaps even paying out of their own pocket for the engineering staff to help him/her build a demonstrator?

This company is based in Israel.

Comment: Where is this happening? Laws on this vary by country/state.

Comment: The exact country and (in the case of a few) state or other sub-national government region would be helpful.   Unlike the U.S. you're not giving much away be giving those as the other Common Law nations tend to be either Federations with large member states or unitairy or devolved unitary states.

Comment: OP updated accordingly.

Comment: "anything an employee comes up with, at any time (e.g. during weekends and completely unrelated to work) is the property of the company.". That is probably unenforceable or flat out void. Companies can not usually claim ownership over IP produced outside work hours. A good Isreali lawyer might be needed to shed light on this.

Comment: @Polygome This type of agreement would be void in CA as a matter of law and public policy. Do you have any reason to believe it would not be valid under Israeli law?

Comment: Yes, a senior employee took an unpaid sabbatical, went on to develop something *tenuously* related to his work and got sued by his former employers. He settled out of court.